# Handlebars: each array of objects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

for some reason I can't get Handlebars to loop my array of records to work. I also have my code on jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Tonyvu/ncr6nyta/.

I have the following array:

```
Array(2)
0: {userid: "jd1234", fullName: "John Doe"}
1: {userid: "jd4567", fullName: "John doe"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

HTML table

```
<table id="Tbl"> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Bobby Jones - bj1234</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My script looks like this:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each records}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{fullName}} - {{attuid}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}  
</script>
<script>
$(function($) {
  var devlist = [
    {userid: "jd1234", fullName: "John Doe"},
    {userid: "jd4567", fullName: "John doe"}
   ];
  var csTemplate = $("#template").html();
  var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(csTemplate);
  $("#Tbl tbody").append(compiledTemplate({records:devlist}));
});
</script>
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ncr6nyta/1/  works fine for me, once I made the `compiledTemplate()` match what you have in your question.  I also changed the library to be the non amd version one, but other than that, your logic already works

Comment: D'oh, Thanks Taplar!